# Joomla 3.2 header module disappeared

Tags: joomla

My header slideshow module disappeared all of the sudden. I have double checked configuration.php and module menu assignment and reinstalled my slideshow module but nothing was wrong. Would you please help me? 
Thank you in advance.
www.totalshabake.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Neil for your hint. I found the solution. I added if statement as below before my template javascript file and it worked like a charm.

if(typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {

//copy and paste your jQuery core code here
 //.................................................
 //.................................................

}

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you have a MooTools / jQuery conflict. From your source code I can see that jQuery is loading before MooTools:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/plugins/system/jqueryeasy/jquerynoconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/media/system/js/mootools-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/media/system/js/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/media/system/js/tabs-state.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/media/system/js/mootools-more.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/media/system/js/modal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Forcing MooTools to load before jQuery or stopping MooTools from loading if you don't need it will probably fix the problem.

You already have jQueryEasy enabled and it may be able to help (read the documentation).

You can also force MooTools to load early by adding the following line high up in the HEAD section of the template index.php file:

```
JHTML::_('behavior.framework', true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply ; I disabled mootools but the problem still exists. Please help me.

Comment: Sorry, I have run out of ideas except to try updating extensions to the latest versions if they aren't already.

Comment: I found the solution ; thank you for your hint. I add if statement as below before my template javascript file and it worked like a charm.

Comment: if(typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
 

 
}

Comment: Please share the solution as an answer and accept it by clicking the green arrow so this question can be marked as resolved.